# C# Automatic deployment/execution from a usb device

Tags: c#, usb

is there any way that a process on my usb will be launched automatically when the usb is connected to the computer?

Is there any way to deploy a file automatically from the usb, each time the usb is connected to the computer?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The user would have to have "auto-play" enabled and then you can setup an autorun file to accomplish this, but it is highly dependent on the users configuration.

It should be noted that this is also a **huge** security concern for many people. Auto-run usb sticks are one of the ways that malware is automatically distributed.

Not trying to tell you your requirements, but I would consider if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Autorun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144200%28VS.85%29.aspx).
I have an old mobile-phone that emulates a cd-drive with a autorun.inf on it. That autorun started an app that let me manage my mobile (calendar, callist, sms) from the computer.

This probably only works if the user has Autorun enabled. It's the first thing I disable.